# Implementing Zoom In/Out in a 2D Camera

Tags: c#, xna, camera, game-engine, xna-4.0

This is my Camera's class, **I don't use Matrices**:

```cs
public static class Camera
{
    private static Vector2 position_ = Vector2.Zero;
    private static Vector2 viewPortSize_ = Vector2.Zero;
    private static Rectangle worldRectangle_ = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
    //Intended to be a value in [0.0f,2.0f]
    //With 0.0f as 0%
    //With 1.0f as 100%
    //With 2.0f as 200%

    private static float zoom_ = 1.0f; 

    public static Vector2 Position
    {
        get { return position_; }
        set
        {
                position_ = new Vector2(
                MathHelper.Clamp(value.X, worldRectangle_.X, worldRectangle_.Width - ViewPortWidth),
                MathHelper.Clamp(value.Y, worldRectangle_.Y, worldRectangle_.Height - ViewPortHeight)
                );
        }
    }

    public static Rectangle WorldRectangle
    {
        get { return worldRectangle_; }
        set { worldRectangle_ = value; }
    }

    public static int ViewPortWidth
    {
        get { return (int)viewPortSize_.X; }
        set { viewPortSize_.X = value; }
    }

    public static int ViewPortHeight
    {
        get { return (int)viewPortSize_.Y; }
        set { viewPortSize_.Y = value; }
    }

    public static Rectangle ViewPort
    {
        get
        {
            return new Rectangle(
                (int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y,
                ViewPortWidth, ViewPortHeight
                );
        }
    }

    public static float Zoom
    {
        get { return zoom_; }
        set { zoom_ = value; }
    }

    public static void Move(Vector2 offset)
    {
        Position += offset;
    }

    public static bool ObjectIsVisible(Rectangle bounds)
    {
        return (ViewPort.Intersects(bounds));
    }

    public static Vector2 Transform(Vector2 point)
    {
        return point - position_;
    }

    public static Rectangle Transform(Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        return new Rectangle(
            rectangle.Left - (int)position_.X,
            rectangle.Top - (int)position_.Y,
            rectangle.Width,
            rectangle.Height);
    }

    public static Vector2 ScreenToWorld(Vector2 screenLocation)
    {
        return screenLocation + position_;
    }

    public static Point PointScreenToWorld(Vector2 screenLocation)
    {
        Vector2 tmp = screenLocation + position_;
        return new Point(Convert.ToInt32(tmp.X), Convert.ToInt32(tmp.Y));
    }

    public static Rectangle ScreenToWorld(Rectangle screenRectangle)
    {
        return new Rectangle(
        screenRectangle.Left + (int)position_.X,
        screenRectangle.Top + (int)position_.Y,
        screenRectangle.Width,
        screenRectangle.Height);
    }
}
```

## Question 1

Consider that I draw a texture like this:

```
public override void Draw(spriteBatch spritebatch)
{
  spriteBatch.Draw(
    myTexture, 
    Camera.Transform(texture.position),
    Color.White);
}
```

What is the right way to make this `Draw` call to also zoom the texture using Camera's `zoom_` value? I really have no idea.

## Question 2

Consider that I draw a set of textures like this:

```
 public static void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
 {
    //They draw each inside a personal RenderTarget2D
    DrawBackgroundLayers(spriteBatch);
    DrawInteractiveLayers(spriteBatch);
    DrawForegroundLayers(spriteBatch);

    graphicsDevice_.SetRenderTarget(null);
    graphicsDevice_.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
    spriteBatch.Draw(background_layers_render_, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(interactive_layers_render_, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(foreground_layers_render_, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

In this way, the answer of the first question is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

misiMe,

You have references to X and Y, but no reference to Z, the third dimension.

See the following MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747437(v=vs.110).aspx

I used to pick a value for Z, and divide (things farther way are smaller and appear to be moving more slowly). I remember adding 0.0001 to prevent divide by zero.

Comment: misiMe, this is a very deep subject and I suggest reading the link above, along with other articles regarding 3D->2D transforms. The direct answer to your question posted is that you're not taking in to account the Z value of your points.

Comment: After thinking about this more, your camera does have a Z value, that's your zoom. Your points are all 2D, so they all have a Z of 0. You now need to translate all of your points before displaying them. Most people use matrix for this, but one thing you can do is divide your X's and Y'z by the Z value of the camera (z would represent a distance).